# How to establish getter & setter for secondary constructor in data class for kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, methods, get, set, data-class

I need a **data class** with **two different constructors** as shown. But how do I do **getter & setter for the secondary constructor** of **data class** in Kotlin? I tried multiple changes, not able to figure it out. In the below snippet, I am not getting the right **import** for **get()** and **set()**

```
data class user(var phone: String) {
    constructor(phone: String, name : String) : this(phone) {
        var name: String = name
        get()= field
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want two constructors, one which only requires a "phone" argument and another which requires both a "phone" and "name" argument. Overall, your data class will have two properties regardless of which constructor is used: *phone* and *name*. You could accomplish this with the following:

```kotlin
data class User(var phone: String) {

    var name: String = ""

    constructor(phone: String, name: String) : this(phone) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

However, as this is Kotlin, you should [prefer default parameter values over overloaded functions/secondary constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#default-parameter-values):

```kotlin
data class User(var phone: String, var name: String = "")
```